# Autofill rows according to the category chosen using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```js
<script type = "text/javascript" > 
{
    var mycategory = [];
    mycategory[0] = [
      ["chocos", "55", "20", " choco chips"],
      ["Mylo", "60", "10", "hot drinks"]
    ];
    mycategory[1] = [
      ["chocos", "55", "20", " choco chips"],
      ["Mylo", "60", "10", "hot drinks"],
      ["milky bar", "70", "22", "chocolate"]
    ];
    mycategory[2] = [
      ["milky bar", "70", "22", "chocolate"]
    ];

    function myfunction(value) 
    {
      var category = value.category;
      var table = document.getElementById("tab");
      for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
        var row = table.insertRow(table.length); 
       {
        for (var j = 0; i < table.length; j++) 
        {
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
          var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
          var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        }
      }
    }
  }
 </script>
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <h2> Product category: </h2>
    <select id="demo" onchange="myfunction(this)">
<option value="Category1" >Category1</option>
<option value="Category2">Category2</option>
<option value="Category3">Category3</option>
<option value="None">None</option>
</select>
  </form>
  <h3>JavaScript Arrays</h3>
  <div>
    <table border="4" id="tab">
      <tr>
        <th>Product name </th>
        <th> unit </th>
        <th> safety stock </th>
        <th> Product Category </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[when I select category 1 i wanted 3 rows to be filled likewise for 2 i want two rows and for 3 i want one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozdCW.png) **JAVASCRIPT**: I have an array with three categories. when i select one category, the items inside that category has to display in the table. When i click category 1 two rows has to be filled, when I click catgory 2 three rows has to be filled , when I click category 3 one row has to be filled.

Comment: what issue you are facing.. have u tried anything yet

Comment: post your code.

Comment: So you have described what you need to do - now what? What are the issues you are facing when implementing it?

Comment: The content you've posted is not **JavaScript**. JS has some cool stuffs with curly braces. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @mathur I created an array var mycategory= [];
  mycategory[0] = [["chocos", "55", "20", " choco chips"],["Mylo", "60", "10", "hot drinks"]];
  mycategory[1] = [["chocos", "55", "20", " choco chips"],["Mylo", "60", "10", "hot drinks"],["milky bar", "70", "22", "chocolate"]];
  mycategory[2]=[["milky bar", "70", "22", "chocolate"]]; and that slect box, I dont know to proceed further

Comment: @Nancy_bts It would be better if you edited your original post with the code, and tried to elaborate.

Comment: @SindreKjr tbh my code looks horrible, let me edit it a bit and then post